# How can the same verb, gaschier, mean "to stain, soil" and "to soak, wash"?

Tags: étymologie

I am  befuddled that

> [Old French *gaschier* **"to stain, soil; soak, wash"** (Modern French *gâcher*) is from Frankish **waskan*, from the same Germanic source.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/wash#etymonline_v_4849)

Why? Because the verbs **"stain, soil"** and **"soak, wash"** are polar opposites! Conversely, when children stain and soil their clothes, they ARE NOT washing their clothes! Their parents must soak and wash clothes to REMOVE stains and soils — NOT to stain and soil the clothes!

Comment: So which one is brainwashing? *Wash* is sometimes ambiguous as to the effect as well. It all depends on what you wash stuff with.

Comment: XIIIe siècle, gaschier, « **remuer dans l’eau, laver sommairement** ». Issu du francique *waskôn, « laver, détremper ».https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9G0019 You act as if those meanings all appeared simultaneously. They did not.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I am again befuddled. Why did you bring up "brainwashing"? I never wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé,](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/g%C3%A2cher) and the [Dictionnaire du Moyen Français](http://zeus.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?LEM=g%E2cher;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;AFFICHAGE=0;MENU=menu_dmf;;ISIS=isis_dmf2020.txt;MENU=menu_recherche_dictionnaire;OUVRIR_MENU=1;ONGLET=dmf2020;OO1=2;OO2=1;s=s0e2329c8;LANGUE=FR;), it seems that in the 13th and 14th centuries, it meant *to soak*, not *to wash*, and it was applied to salted fish (which was soaked to get rid of some of the salt) and to plaster (which was soaked in preparation for using it).

I can't find any etymology for the word in Old French, beyond what is in Etymonline, but if you soak something in mud or another dirty liquid, you soil it and possibly stain it.

Answer (score 1):

> GÂCHER v. tr. est une réfection graphique (XVIIe s.) de *gascher* (XVe
> s.), *gaschier* (1260), issu du francique °*waskôn* « laver, détremper
> » restitué d'apprès l'ancien haut allemand *wascan* et le moyen
> néerlandais *wasschen* (Cf. allemand *waschen*, anglais *to wash*). P.
> Guiraud suggère pour origine un gallo-roman °*vasicare* « touiller
> comme le raisin dans la cuve », dérivé de *vas* « vase » (→ 1 *vase* ;
> Cf. italien *vasca* « cuve du pressoir »).
>
> *Gâcher* a signifié « remuer dans l'eau, laver sommairement » (d'abord le poisson pour le dessaler), d'où vient (déb. XIVe s.) gâcher du
> mortier, du plâtre « le délayer ». De ce sens, évoquant comme le
> premier un travail rapide et parfois sommaire, sont probablement issus
> les sens figurés « donner sa marchandise trop bon marché » (1741) puis
> « faire un travail sans soin » (1808 ; Cf. *bousiller*) et, par
> figure, « manquer qqch. faute d'en tirer profit » (1872).
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. Rey, chez
> Robert, 2011 ]

Just some thoughts since I have no expertise. But consider in French you have other verbs such as *souiller*, *tacher*, or *salir*. Arguably the first two can match *soil* and *stain*. I've never heard anyone saying someone "a gâché son pantalon", for instance. *Gâcher* is not equal to soil/stain if only by virtue of a different usage. As a native speaker, I didn't know *gâcher du plâtre* meant diluting it ; but I would understand "gâcher le plâtre" as ruining it, not soiling it. Also consider the difference between a deep wash and what you would consider as merely cleaning up/rinsing ; are you *washing* a fish? Relying only on the casual meanings for these words, through the English language on top of that, won't provide you with much insight imho. What you most likely have here is an extension of the idea of the summary or "not careful" cleaning. Whether careful or "careless", a cleaning remains a cleaning.

The fact a word in French is based on some Germanic language doesn't mean it remains linked to this original language and that you can pull it out of the bag hundreds of years later and compare it to other words and usage in English and that it will fit right back in. With respect, the French language doesn't answer to the English one.